# XCode 7.2 unable to view memory profiling info / Device is offline in instruments

Tags: c++, objective-c, xcode, memory-management, instruments

I'm running an iOS demo using an Objective C++ library (some .mm files) and would like to profile the app's memory usage with Instruments. However, I see that the debug tab does not show any memory information.

[image]

[image]

Attempting to profile the app in instruments shows my device, but it is grayed out and says it's offline

[image]

**How can I fix my XCode to allow for memory debugging/profiling of that project?** Does it have something to do with using an Objective C++ libraries?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can check whether your project's Zombie Objects are enabled.

Open:

> Product -> Scheme -> Edit scheme -> run-Diagnostics -> Enable Zombie Objects

If open please close then run.

[image: This is the screenshot Picture]

EDIT: The issue is twofold, the "unable to profile on device is an iOS 9.x.x bug, here's a support thread: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/16242 . Here are the steps one of the posters suggested:

- Power down the device completely.
- Unplug the device from your Mac.
- Close Xcode and Instruments.
- Restart the device & plug it back in
  once it has restarted.
- Re-launch Xcode.
- Here, my device was disabled
  and Xcode indicated that the device was not available for use.
- Clean,
  Build, Profile (Command-I).
- When Instruments is launched the device
  was enabled.
- Upon selecting it, a message was displayed with the
  title "Enable this device for development?" and message "This will
  open Xcode and enable this device for development."
- Click "Open
  Xcode".
- Here I did not notice anything being displayed - no
  additional messages indicating anything had been done or that the
  device was or was not available for development.
- Opening the Devices
  window, the device appeared to be available. Here I was able to
  select the device in Instruments and profile it. I was also again
  able to delete installed apps from the Devices window.

Comment: Xcode 7.3.1 and iOS 9.3.4 here. It was working perfectly and it stopped all of a sudden. After I restarted the phone and plugged it again, Xcode gave me a "unknown error occurred" after trying to Profile again. I then restarted Xcode and next time it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Desinstalling the app from the device and then profiling works for me.